# Thymeleaf - set attributes for objects in forms with hidden inputs

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I got this peace of html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{${cartServiceBaseUrl}+'/addCatalogItemToCart'}" th:object="${cartCatalogItem}"  method="post">
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${cartId}" th:field="*{cartId}" />
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${catalogItem.catalogItemId}" th:field="*{catalogItemId}" />
                <input type="submit" value="add to cart" />
            </form>
```

Unfortunately **both values are null** and I dont really understand why, because both values, `cartId` and `catalogItem.catalogItemId` are available on the page. 
How can I properly pass them?

**Java endpoint**

```
@PostMapping(ADD_CATALOG_ITEM_TO_CART)
    public void addCatalogItemToCart(@ModelAttribute CartCatalogItem cartCatalogItem, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

**Full HTML:**

```
<h1 th:text="${catalog.name}">...</h1>

<a th:href="@{${customerServiceBaseUrl}+'/home/'+__${cartId}__}">home</a>

<p th:text="'Catalog ID:'+${catalog.catalogId}"></p>
<p th:text="'Name: '+${catalog.name}"></p>
<table>
    <th:block th:each="catalogItem : ${catalog.catalogItems}">
        <tr>
            <th>article id</th>
            <th>catalogitem id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${catalogItem.articleId}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${catalogItem.catalogItemId}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${catalogItem.name}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${catalogItem.price}">...</td>
            <td><form action="#" th:action="@{${cartServiceBaseUrl}+'/addCatalogItemToCart'}" th:object="${cartCatalogItem}"  method="post">
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${cartId}" th:field="*{cartId}" />
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${catalogItem.catalogItemId}" th:field="*{catalogItemId}" />
                <input type="submit" value="add to cart" />
            </form></td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

**My goal: assign attributes to objects with hidden input fields and pass them for the controller methods.**

Comment: Can you post the `CartCatalogItem` bean code and the method annotated with `@GetMapping` (or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not set your values from controller that's why there are both values null.
Use this code on your controller.
For example:

```
Model and View model=new Model and View ("Your thyme leaf template name");
model.put('your key name by which you an access on your thyme leaf 
 page',cart Id);
 return model;
```

This will work.